# How to properly extract content from a blog article?

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract content from a blog article like this:

```
static void GetBlogData (string blogPostUrl)
{
    string blogPostContent = null;

    WebClient client = new WebClient ();
    //client.Headers.Add (HttpRequestHeader.Referer, "http://www.stackoverflow.com");

    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter ("/home/nanda/projects/mono/common/article");

    try
    {
        blogPostContent = client.DownloadString (blogPostUrl);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Term.PrintLn ("Unable to download\n{0}", ex.Message);
    }

    if (blogPostContent != null) 
    {
        writer.WriteLine (blogPostContent);
    } 

    else
    {
        Term.PrintLn ("No content found");
    }
}
```

I am aware that this is too simple of an approach, but I want to know why I am unable to extract content from some URLs like they have a block or something. How can I detect if a website/blog is blocking me from downloading its content?

Comment: They might be expecting you to send a cookie or to be logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A website cannot block you from downloading its content without blocking the site's consultation from a browser.

If your download fails, it means either:

a) your url is wrong

b) the website needs some form of identification and your request lacks something (probably a cookie)

Comment: How can I add cookies to a request?